# Visual Studio Code interface crash on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, crash, visual-studio-code

My VSCode simply doesn't show the interface (codeline, folders and files on the left, terminal, etc.). I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and have installed the VSCode snap package.

Example how my VSCode looks now:

[image: Example how my Vs Code looks now]

Things I've already tried:

- Reinstall VSCode
- Reinstall Ubuntu
- Using `code --disable-gpu` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760824/the-letters-wont-appear-in-vscode-ubuntu-20-04-m1-proarm64)

Comment: Seems like after multiple tries with code --disable-gpu really solve the problem.
However, I needed multiple tentative and I still do not know what could cause the problem.

Comment: Snap packages generally do not depend on the OS and have everything inside the snap, so ... you might want to file a bugreport. It could be due to running out of memory... 1st step I tend to take: start the program from command line and see if there are errors thrown that look like about the issue (a debugger will want that info anyways ;))